# Get one results of each value of column

Tags: solr

I want to perform a search such that for top values of a column , i can get 'n' number of results.

for example
consider country as one options having possible values as
1. USA (200 enteries)
2. UK (180 enteries)
3. CANADA (160 enteries)
4. ARGENTINA (140 enteries)
5. BRAZIL (120 enteries)

i want for top 3 countries i.e USA,UK,CANANDA i can get one row for every country using only single query?

Comment: You should have referred faceting yourself. Also there is result grouping and pivot facets(havent tried mysqlf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [Solr Field Collapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) (Grouping).

use `group=true&group.field=country` to enable grouping on country field

This will help you group on a single valued field e.g. Country and limit the number of groups (`rows`) as well number of results per group (`group.limit`) allowing the ability to expand.

Complete list for [parameters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing#Request_Parameters)

Comment: what param name should i need to append ?